# ¿Cómo compruebo que no haya un archivo con el mismo nombre con OpenFileDialog en C#?

Tags: c#

El caso es que tengo un OpenFileDialog para escoger dónde y con qué nombre crear un fichero. Pero no comprueba que ya haya otro con el mismo nombre en la misma ruta y si lo creo lo reemplaza automáticamente, sin preguntar ni nada. ¿Cómo podría hacer esa comprobación?
Gracias de antemano, salu2

Comment: Utilizas OpenFileDialog para crear un fichero? No sería mejor utilizar un SaveFileDialog? Con esto, una vez creado el fichero le indicas donde guardarlo, si no me equivoco te avisa si ya existe un fichero con el nombre que le has dado

Comment: Puedes simplemente buscar el fichero, si lo encuentra existe, y si no, pues no.

Comment: Que tal con [`File.Exists`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.io.file.exists(v=vs.110).aspx) antes de guardarlo?

Comment: Debes usar SaveFileDialog en lugar de OpenFileDialog. Tienes un ejemplo aquí: https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/sfezx97z(v=vs.110).aspx